# Checkout Bitbucket Repo Branch in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh, bitbucket

I am new with Jenkins and trying to create a pipeline and checkout the private BitBucket repository from Jenkins and then install dependencies and then create build.

But I am having issue in the first step while checkout the repository branch.
I have set the credentials and SSH link as well.

Here is the Error:

```
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential 02cb4299-3a20-424f-a541-1771e5b2e0b9
C:\Users\ahsan.alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse --resolve-git-dir C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\SCM-Pipline\.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
C:\Users\ahsan.alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin\git.exe config remote.origin.url ssh:///git@bitbucket.org:Arsalanakhtar123/etisalat-jenkins.git/ # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from ssh:///git@bitbucket.org:Arsalanakhtar123/etisalat-jenkins.git/
C:\Users\ahsan.alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin\git.exe --version # timeout=10
git --version # 'git version 2.37.0.windows.1'
C:\Users\ahsan.alam\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --force --progress -- ssh:///git@bitbucket.org:Arsalanakhtar123/etisalat-jenkins.git/ +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
```

Here is the code:

```
pipeline {
 agent any
  stages {
  stage('Git Checkout') {
  steps { 
    git branch: 'master',
        credentialsId: '<credentialIdsHere>', // changed
        url: 'ssh://git@bitbucket.org:company/repo.git/' // changed
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Also I have specify the git.exe path

[image]

Comment: Try using HTTPS to connect with bitbucket instead of SSH to see if its a problem with how you set up SSH

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SSH is working, meaning you can execute manually a `git ls-remote` (for instance) to that SSH URL, I would recommend the syntax (for said SSH URL):

```
ssh://git@bitbucket.org/company/repo.git
                      ^^^ (/, not :)
# or
git@bitbucket.org:company/repo.git/
                ^^^ (OK, but no ssh:// prefix)
```